# Things to consider when creating a searchable customer database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, indexing

Our company currently has a large number of separate customer databases which have existed for years for different purposes. Online Sales, in store sales, marketing, finance etc etc. The list goes on. Probably about 10 different database.

I have been tasked with the creation of a new "SINGLE" database, syncing the old databases with the new one and developing a API so that we can modify the other products to hook up into the new DB.

One of the key features that I need is the database to be searchable in an efficient way. Since we are joining a large number of databases together there will be a lot of customers.

Lets assume by Customer table contains this info.

```
[CustomerID]    [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Title]         [nchar](20)            NULL,
[FirstName]     [nchar](50)            NOT NULL,
[MiddleName]    [nchar](50)            NULL,
[LastName]      [nchar](50)            NOT NULL,
[Alias]         [nchar](100)           NULL,
[DateOfBirth]   [date]                 NULL,
[Gender]        [char](1)              NULL
```

I was thinking i would have a SearchParameters object that would be passed to my API and build a where clause based on that.

```
public class SearchParameters
{
    public long?     CustomerID  {get;set;}
    public string    Title       {get;set;}
    public string    FirstName   {get;set;}
    public string    MiddleName  {get;set;}
    public string    LastName    {get;set;}
    public string    Alias       {get;set;}
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth {get;set;}
    public char?     CustomerID  {get;set;}
}
```

And the WHERE would be:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE 
  (@CustomerID IS NULL OR CustomerID = @CustomerID)
  AND (@Title IS NULL OR Title = @Title)
  AND .... and so on
```

Is this a good approach?

Also what should i consider when it comes to indexing my customer table.

Comment: Its obvious that `CustomerID`is a PK?

Comment: @Hemal What has that to do with anything?

Comment: PK is a must for efficient search.

Comment: @Hemal Its a customer search function. Eg. Customer phones up and they need to find them. The customers not going to know their ID number all the time.

Comment: If people are going to down vote they need to say why!!

Comment: You have supplied `CustomerID` to search for it thats why I am suggesting

Comment: It's not about indexing, such a list of predicates is about `option (recompile)`

Comment: No need to explain and, thats why, downvote facility provided. Though I havent done it.

Comment: I mean, you can not figure it out with a single (or couple of) magic index, but since there is a `recompile` option, server will be able to identify appropriate index at every search run with respect to actual arguments provided.

Comment: Don't worry, though I personally find it rude to downvote w/o an explanation, downvoting that doesn't make sense happens.

Comment: I think to maximize the performance, you should make CustomerId as primary key as it is by default clustered Index so it would be efficient and make non clustered index on the next most searched by column.

Comment: CustomerID is PK already as it seems (by convention) and likely a clustered index. It is not the factor for maximizing performance (search performance and insert performance are different). Actually, in a query it would be odd to have other searches if searching by PK (may happen but unlikely - SQL server is smart enough in optimizing it anyway).

Answer (score 0):

"Is this a good approach?"
Personally, I don't think so.  You'd end up building big queries which might not be that efficient, also exact matches will work and use indexes, but if you start using partial matches everything becomes slower.

Why not look into tools built for searching, such as [full text search?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you would need to rework your structure for effectiveness. Such as nvarchar instead of char (because that too would effect the queries). You probably would have the multiple phones and alike in xml fields (AdventureWorks has sample schema and field).

For the search, since this is also a C# question, what about doing it on the C# side? Something like this (Northwind as a sample):

```
void Main()
{
  string country = ""; //"Brazil"
  string city = ""; //"Sao Paulo"
  DateTime? orderDate = null; //new DateTime(1996,8,28);

  var data = db.Orders
    .Where (c => string.IsNullOrEmpty(country) || c.ShipCountry.StartsWith(country) )
    .Where (c => string.IsNullOrEmpty(city) || c.ShipCity.StartsWith(city) )
    .Where (c => orderDate == null || c.OrderDate == orderDate);

}
```

This effectively works with Linq To SQL and generated SQL is optimized (ie: it doesn't add country search if the value is null).

This second approach, builds a progressive query based on parameters and would also work with Linq To EF besides Linq To SQL:

```
void Main()
{
  string country = ""; //"Brazil"
  string city = ""; //"Sao Paulo"
  DateTime? orderDate = null;//new DateTime(1996,8,28);

  var data = Orders.AsQueryable();

  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(country))
  {
    data = data.Where(c => c.ShipCountry.StartsWith(country));
  }
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(city))
  {
    data = data.Where(c => c.ShipCity.StartsWith(city));
  }
  if (orderDate != null)
  {
    data = data.Where(c => c.OrderDate == orderDate);
  }
}
```